# Microsoft Text Analytics API (v2.1) sample code does not work

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, jsonresponse

I want to use the Sentiment analysis API of Microsoft Azure. I use their sample code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/python) as follows.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
import requests
# pprint is used to format the JSON response
from pprint import pprint

import os

subscription_key = "*********"
endpoint = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics"


sentiment_url = endpoint + "/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment"


documents = {"documents": [
    {"id": "1", "language": "en",
        "text": "I had a wonderful experience! The rooms were wonderful and the staff was helpful."},
    {"id": "2", "language": "en",
        "text": "I had a terrible time at the hotel. The staff was rude and the food was awful."},
    {"id": "3", "language": "es",
        "text": "Los caminos que llevan hasta Monte Rainier son espectaculares y hermosos."},
    {"id": "4", "language": "es",
     "text": "La carretera estaba atascada. Había mucho tráfico el día de ayer."}
]}


headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": subscription_key}
response = requests.post(sentiment_url, headers=headers, json=documents)
sentiments = response.json()
pprint(sentiments)
```

But it only returns `{'error': {'code': '404', 'message': 'Resource not found'}}` What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played much with this side of the analytics, so I might be totally off base, but it looks to me like you've got "text/analytics" doubled up.

```
endpoint = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics"
sentiment_url = endpoint + "/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment"
```

would give a final result of 
https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment

and it's probably supposed to just be:

https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.1/sentiment

Comment: Good guess (you can see the url in the developer console of the API: https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics-v2-1/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9/console)

Comment: i change the endpoint to 'https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com' and it works. thank you Hilton